# Como usar "request unique" na seguinte situação

Tags: php, laravel-5, http-request

Tenho dois métodos na Controller que tem a função de salvar um cheque novo e outro que atualiza o cheque com o editar.

Os dois métodos passam pelo Request antes de inserir no banco, porem o Request valida se o cheque não é existente. Funciona perfeito para o novo, porém ao editar um cheque, o Request passa de novo e acaba dando conflito com o próprio numero.

Como evitar que ele olhe para o número que esta sendo editado apenas e pode sim ser o mesmo nesse caso exceção.

Controller

```
public function atualizar(ChequeRequest $request) {
    $id = $request->input('id');
    $contaUpdate = Cheque::findOrFail($id);
    $input = $request->all();
    $contaUpdate->fill($input)->save();
    Session::put('success', "Cheque alterado com sucesso!");
    return redirect()->action($this->viewRetorno);
}

public function salvar(ChequeRequest $request) {

    Cheque::create($request->all());
    Session::put('success', "Cheque adicionado com sucesso!");
    return redirect()->action($this->viewRetorno);
}
```

Request Class

```
 public function rules() {

    return [
        'agencia' => 'required|max:255',
        'idBanco' => 'required|numeric',
        'conta' => 'required|max:255',
        'numero' => "required|unique:tb_cheques,numero,NULL,{$this->id},deleted_at,NULL",
        'data_cheque' => "required|date_format:Y-m-d",
        'valor' => 'required|numeric',
        'observacoes' => 'max:255',

    ];
}
```

Comment: Rafael, olha na documentação ( https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-unique )

Comment: mais não consigo usar esse ignore ali no meu código sem usar o laravel 5.7? to usando laravel 5.0. seria interessante eu conseguir da ignore como mais um parâmetro do unique.

Answer (score 1):

a solução ficou a seguinte

```
'conta' => "required|max:255|unique:tb_contas_bancarias,conta,{$this->id},id,deleted_at,NULL",
```

resposta estava neste link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374995/check-if-name-is-unique-among-non-deleted-items-with-laravel-validation